# Parse XML Ajax, data appearing after the html

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml-parsing

I am parseing xml from an AJAX get request using the code below, why are all of the elements appearing after the html?  What am I doing wrong?

```
<li><section><blockquote><p></p></blockquote></section></li>
<h1>QUOTE</h1>
<img class="truffle" src="Content/Images/truffles/pecan-caramel-truffle.png?text=pecan-caramel-truffle">
<h2>NAME</h2>
```

Parsing of the AJAX

```
$(result).find('ContestResult').each(function () {
   var name = $(this).find('FirstName').text();
   var imgName = $(this).find('ImageName').text();
   var quote = $(this).find('quote').text();
   var theName = "NAME";

   var sliderItem = '<li><section><blockquote><p>' + quote + '</p></li></blockquote>';
   sliderItem += '<h1>~' + name + '</h1></section>';
   sliderItem += '<img class="yep" src="' + imgName + '" />';
   sliderItem += '<h2>' + theName + '</h2>';
   sliderItem += '</li>';

   $("ul#slider").append(sliderItem);

   i++; //Iterate variable});
```

Comment: Where is your `slider` list in the above HTML?

Comment: A ul with the most recent li being pulled from the database

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling that this happens because you don't have a closing `</ul>`. So the jQuery `append()` function tries to find the last character in the `ul`, and believes your HTML to be a part of this `ul` as well.

I have created a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/sudipta/93AqB/

This is all the change I did in the HTML and it seems to add your data before the HTML:

```
<ul id="slider">
<li>
    <section>
        <blockquote>
            <p>Foo</p>
        </blockquote>
    </section>
</li>
</ul>

<h1>QUOTE</h1>
<img class="truffle" src="Content/Images/truffles/pecan-caramel-truffle.png?text=pecan-caramel-truffle">
<h2>NAME</h2>
```

Comment: Thanks for you help but I found the reason, you need to split out each element, or it will not parse correctly.  $("ul.ClassName").append('<li>' + '<section>' + '<blockquote>' + '<p>' + $(this).find('Quote').text() +

Comment: There is something else wrong then - this cannot be the reason. Take a look at the fiddle link I posted and feel free to modify it with/without the separate elements. It works either way